# Были прецеденты? Напомните(,) когда

Tags: пунктуация

***Были прецеденты? Напомните(,) когда.***

Что здесь с запятой?

//---------------
Поясню свои сомнения.

Розенталь в принципе-то допускает постановку запятой перед одиночным словом (http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=260#pp260), но в условиях определенного контекста, и потом, меня интересует именно общее правило, а не исключения. Дело в том, что без запятой фраза выглядит совершенно по-уродски.

А общее правило у Розеталя формулируется предельно просто:

> 3. [запятая не ставится], если придаточная часть состоит из одного
>    союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия)...

Рождается крамольная мысль, что формулировка Розенталя нуждается в некотором пояснении, что, дескать, не всякое одиночное (в рассматриваемом смысле) "союзное слово" является придаточным.

(+) =======
Комментарий по итогом обсуждения.
Я не вижу причин вносить какие-то коррективы в вопрос. Но могу уточнить, что вопрос не о запятой как таковой, а о грамматике фразы.

Разжевываю.

***Напомните, когда это было(?)***
Здесь возможно двоякое толкование грамматики. Если ставить вопросительный знак, то "напомните" здесь де-факто выполняет роль вводного. Без него - скорее всего "когда это было" - обычное придаточное. Хотя с некоторой фантазией все равно можно считать "напомните" - вводным. Запятая в обоих случаях незыблема, поэтому для практике вопрос о грамматике не актуален.
А вот когда "придаточное" сокращается до одного слова возникает некоторая путаница, которую с помощью известного приема двоечника (не знаешь, как писать - замени фразу) не решить по сути.
Возможно, я ошибаюсь в своей логике, буду рад услышать, в чем именно.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос. Почему-то никто больше этот момент не рассматривает. Даже у Лопатина об исключениях не сказано.

Это решается логическими ударениями:
*Напомните когдА.* || На первом слове нет ударения, его перетягивает союзное слово.
*НапОмните, когда.* || Так лучше звучит, на мой взгляд.

У Розенталя сказано о логическом выделении, то есть о логических ударениях.

Возможно, здесь связано с повелительным наклонением. Ведь у Розенталя пример тоже с ним:
*Что же надо делать? НаучИте, что.*
Наверно, для глагола в повелительном наклонении характерно подчёркивание (логическое выделение), в связи с чем допустима запятая.

Comment: Вы знаете, меня совершенно в данном случае  не вдохновляет разбираться с зависимостью пунктуации от логического ударения. Я вижу, что без запятой **смысл** какой-то другой. Как я сказал - идиотский. А по Розенталю запятая - максимум факультативна. Могу добавить только то, что далеко не в первый раз сталкиваюсь с этим внутренним убеждением, что запятая в подобных случаях просто необходима, но впервые не могу свести её к требованиям контекста/акцентирования. Почему и возникла мысль о необходимости вводить альтернативную розенталевской грамматику.

Comment: Дело в том, что больше ни у кого о таких исключениях речи нет. Скорее всего, он мыслил на основе логических ударений. Ведь только один пример ему удалось найти, и то там другое. Так что "хочу ссылку" здесь не сработает. Остаётся как раз только разбираться. Интересно, какой у вас другой смысл (идиотский). Может быть, это даст новое поле для анализа. Раз уж у вас вопрос о грамматике, о чём сказано не было, то задайте его непосредственно.

Answer (score 0):

А может, пунктуация здесь должна быть такая: *Были прецеденты? Напомните: когда?*

Comment: Ваша пунктуация в лучшем случае факультативна. То есть вопрос о запятой никак не снимает.

Comment: Снимает. Если без запятой фраза выглядит «по-уродски» и с запятой тоже вызывает вопросы — значит, нужно что-то иное.

Comment: Ну это вы рассуждаете как корректор. А я как исследователь: стоит задача и она должна быть решена. Именно она, а не другая, чем-то похожая.

Comment: Какая задача стоит? Ставить ли запятую, если без запятой фраза не нравится? «Мне бы ваши заботы, господин учитель!» :)

Comment: Задача стоит в определении грамматики фразы и уточнении (при необходимости) формулировки Розенталя. Вот вам "мои заботы". Забирайте.

Comment: Розенталь прав в том отношении, что придаточная часть МОЖЕТ состоять из одного союзного слова и что в запятой перед такой придаточной частью нет необходимости. Если автор считает, что ему такая грамматика не годится — в его власти использовать другую грамматику.

Comment: Насчет "другой грамматики" - это вы, простите, увлеклись. А насчет Розенталя - вернитесь всё-таки к моему вопросу - и не выдумывайте собственных постановок. Меня не особо интересует, в чем Р. прав. Вопрос в том, в чем он (возможно) не совсем прав. На этом, простите, вынужден откланяться. движок уже ругается.

Comment: «Вопрос в том, в чем он (возможно) не совсем прав» — нет такого вопроса. О чём Р. писал, в том он прав. О чём он написать не успел — о том нам придётся размышлять самим. Ибо иначе, увы, никак, и не надо в этой связи бояться и пугать других :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132372/discussion-between-behemothus-and--).